# Why is Visual Studio not displaying correct autoCompletion suggestions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

I am using Unity with Visual Studio Code. However, VS Code is not giving me correct autocompletion suggestion. Below is a snippet of what it displays
[image]

Once I select any of the suggestions, I am getting this :

[image]

Anyone ever experienced the same? How can I get correct suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio: Tools -> Options -> Intellicode set to C#

In Unity: Edit -> Preferences -> External Script Editor, link up your Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you need go to the tools move to the options and then set the lang to C#
And also you have to link up your Visual Studio to the unity software
You can do that by going to the
Edit - preferences and external script editor the you can link up your visual studio